# try to authenticate login, submit nothing happened

Tags: python, html, django

login.html in (authenticate/login.html)

```
{% extends "events/base.html" %}

{% block content %} 
<h1>Login</h1>
<br><br>
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <form>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputUserName" class="form-label">User name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>
  </form>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
</form>

<br><br>
{% endblock content %}
```

when click the submit button nothing happened

urls.py in (events)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

urls.py in (members)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login_user/', views.login_user, name='login'),
]
```

urls.py in (myclub_webesite)

```
rom django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('events.urls')),
    path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),
]
```

views.py in (members)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages


def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(
                request, ("There Was An Error Logging In, Try Again..."))
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
```

setting are put in members
i have try use other code
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
and same nothing happened

Comment: Why do you have two nested `<form>` tags?

Comment: Right.  That's the issue.  The inner `<form>` is the one that takes effect, and because it doesn't have a `method`, it will come in as `GET`.  Just delete the inner `<form>` tags.

Comment: django version 3.1.5

Comment: thx, omg this is a big mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
### You have used 2 form tag so there was an error  

    {% extends "events/base.html" %}
    
    {% block content %} 
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <br><br>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
    
     
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputUserName" class="form-label">User name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>
    
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>
    
    <br><br>
    {% endblock content %}
```

#### Views.py I change the success message to error message because if there is an error then user so will see error message not success

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages


def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            ### success -> error 
            messages.error(
                request, ("There Was An Error Logging In, Try Again..."))
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form tag, define the appropriate API method:

```
<form method='POST'>
.
.
.
</form>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
```